# VS Code - syntax highlighting color customization for "import module"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, themes

I want to change the color of imported modules
[Text Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB7TB.png)

I understand I should edit the settings.json file like so: [Settings Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dryzc.png)

But I don't see any key for "module" or "package"

What do? Thanks!

Comment: use the extension **Highlight**

Comment: the syntax highlight is language agnostic, it works with scopes determined by the language TextMate file

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following code to your `setting.json`:

```
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "rules": {
      "module:python": "#ff0000",
    }
  }
```

At the same time, the [document](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release#semantic-highlighting) also explains more detailed settings.